# Extracting multiple RDS MySQL tables to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Rather new to AWS Data Pipeline so any help will be appreciated. I have used the pipeline template *RDStoS3CopyActivity* to extract all contents of a table in RDS MySQL. Seems to be working good. But there are 90 other tables to be extracted and dumped to S3. I cannot imagine craeting 90 pipelines or one for each table.

What is the best approach to resolving this task? How could pipeline be instructed to iterate though a list of *the table names*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will ever get responded. However, in this early stage of exploration, I have developed a pipeline that seems to fit a preliminary purpose -- extracting from 10 RDS MySQL tables and copying each to their respective sub-bucket on S3.

The logic is rather simple.

- Configure connection for the RDS MySQL.
- Extract data by specifying in "Select Query" field for each table.
- Drop a Copy Activity and link up for each table above. It runs on a specified EC2 instance. If you're running expensive query, make sure you choose the appropriate EC2 instance with enough CPU and memory. This step copies the extracted dump, which lives temporarily in ec2 tmp filesystem, to a designated S3 bucket you will set up next.
- Finally, the designated / target destination.

By default, data extracted and loaded to S3 bucket will be comma separated. If you need it to be tab delimited, then in the last target S3 destination:
 - Add an optional field.. > select Data Format.
 - Create a new Tab Separated. This will appear under the category of 'Others'.
 - Give it a name. I call it Tab Separated.
 - Type: TSV. Hover mouse over 'Type' to learn more of other data formats.
 - Column separator: \t (i could leave this blank as type was already specified as tsv)

Screenshot
[image: My workflow example]
 -

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are all in the same RDS Why not use a SQLActivity pipeline with a SQL statement containing multiple unload commands to S3?

You can just write one query and use one pipeline.

Comment: Instead of a "select * from table", can we write a mysqldump -uroot -p schema tablename > tablename.sql in the script field? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @dat789 Whoops. I think your solution will work the best. I read that as 'Redshift' not 'RDS' offers an Unload and Copy option directly to and from S3. Your answer probably works best and looks like it does some of the stuff here -
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copymysql-cli.html

Comment: While the solution I posted may work, it is also useful to note that AWS Data Pipeline has a default of 100 objects per pipeline. Every object you drop on to the canvas counts as one. For me, each table is unique (can't union), I have to have 3 objects {rds mysql object to select from table name; copy object activity; output to S3 datanode} per table. You can request AWS to increase the number of allowed objects in your pipeline but it would be a pain in the neck to be doing more than 100 objects. I have opted for another solution.